# Cypress get the data from cy.route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I am using Cypress to test a ReactJs application. I need to grab some data from this request:

```js
cy.route('GET', '/user', 'fixture:USER/user').as('user');
```

I tried this:

```js
Given('Check user', () => {
  cy.route('GET', '/user', 'fixture:USER/user').as('user');
  cy.wait('@user')
    .then(({ requestBody, responseBody, status }) => {
      expect(requestBody.name).to.eq('admin');
    });
});
```

But i got this:

```html
Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: user. No request ever occurred.Learn more
```

Is there a possibility to get the result of the above request. I need this to check if user has a specific role, but the information about the user role is returned by the request above.
Who can help with this?

Comment: Why use cy.route() it's been depricated.

Comment: @SuchAnIgnorantThingToDo-UKR, then how to change my code?

Comment: @user16695029, what kind of mistakes i have?

Answer (score 2):

Although deprecated, you have to begin with `cy.server()` somewhere before you call `cy.route()`.

Also, you have to set your `cy.route()` or `cy.intercept()` before you anticipate the call to occur. Most of the times it will be around a `cy.visit()`.

```js
cy.intercept('GET', '/user', {fixture: 'user.json'}).as('user')
// some code that will make a request to /user
cy.wait('@user')
  .then( response => {
    // code to use fixture data
  })
```

Comment: regarding this `// some code that will make a request to /user`. The request occurs after the user is logged in, without clicking anything. Like in `useEffect` in react after the dom is mounted. How to trigger the request in this case?

Comment: So why don't you try setting the intercept up before login occurs?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
Given('Check user', () => {
  cy.intercept('GET','/user', { fixture: 'user.json' }).as('user');
  cy.wait('@user')
    .then(({ request }) => {
      expect(request.name).to.eq('admin');
    });
});
```

Comment: if i do this i get: Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: user. No request ever occurred.Learn more . How to solve this?

Comment: I tried it with an angular app where I called the `/user`-route. It works as expected. You have to set the interceptor before the route is called. In this case before the user is logged in.